# Fusion chart showing No Data to display in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, charts, ecmascript-6, fusioncharts

I am doing react native application. In that, I am trying to showing bar chart. So, I am using `Fusion Chart`, It is mandatory to use this library in my application. So, I followed this library installation and it was successful. But, Data is not showing at all.

> No Data to display showing in screen.

My code is

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      type: 'bar2d',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      dataFormat: 'json',
      dataSource: {
        chart: {
            captionFontSize: '16',
            subcaptionFontSize: '14',
            showAlternatevGridColor: '0',
            numDivLines: '0',
            valueFontColor: '#ffffff',
            yAxisMinValue: '0',
            yAxisMaxValue: '100',
            showYAxisValues: '0',
            // "canvasBorderColor" : "#b3ffb3",
            canvasBgColor: '#ffffff,#e6eeff',
            canvasTopMargin: '100',
            paletteColors: '#990000',
            usePlotGradientColor: '1',
            plotGradientColor: '#ff8080',
            divLineAlpha: '0',
            plotSpacePercent: '60',
            useDataPlotColorForLabels: '1',
            showPercentInTooltip: '0',
            showLegend: '1',
            showLabels: '0',
            showValues: '0',
            placeValuesInside: '1',
            showBorder: '0'
          },
          data: [
            {
              label: 'Travel & Leisure',
              value: '41'
            },
            {
              label: 'Advertising/Marketing/PR',
              value: '39'
            },
            {
              label: 'Other',
              value: '38'
            },
            {
              label: 'Real Estate',
              value: '32'
            },
          ],
          annotations: {
            showBelow: '0',
            autoScale: '1',
            groups: [{
              id: 'user-images',
              items: [{
                id: 'dyn-label-bg',
                color: '#000000',
                align: 'left',
                type: 'text',
                text: 'Best when calm',
                x: '$canvasStartX+0',
                y: '$dataset.0.set.0.ENDY-0'
              }, {
                id: 'dyn-label-bg',
                color: '#000000',
                align: 'left',
                type: 'text',
                text: 'Very Relaxed',
                x: '$canvasStartX+00',
                y: '$dataset.0.set.1.ENDY-0'
              }, {
                id: 'dyn-label-bg',
                color: '#000000',
                align: 'left',
                type: 'text',
                text: 'Mellow',
                x: '$canvasStartX+00',
                y: '$dataset.0.set.2.ENDY-0'
              }, {
                id: 'dyn-label-bg',
                color: '#000000',
                align: 'left',
                type: 'text',
                text: 'Out of Control',
                x: '$canvasStartX+00',
                y: '$dataset.0.set.3.ENDY-0'
              }]
            }]
          }
    }

    };

    this.libraryPath = Platform.select({
      // Specify fusioncharts.html file location
      ios: require('./assets/fusioncharts.html'),
      //android: { uri: 'file:///android_asset/fusioncharts.html' },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>
          FusionCharts Integration with React Native
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.chartContainer}>
          <FusionCharts
            type={this.state.type}
            width={this.state.width}
            height={this.state.height}
            dataFormat={this.state.dataFormat}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            libraryPath={this.libraryPath} // set the libraryPath property
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I have customised this for design. 
Can anyone tell me, Where I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Refer to the sample in the below GitHub link :
https://github.com/fusioncharts/react-native-fusioncharts-samples

Comment: I have already checked them too. If I add annotations,  the issue happens.  Any help

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have correct path of fusioncharts.html 
and uder the package.js in script tag run this command 
"build:assets": "fc-build-assets --fc-template ./src/assets/fusioncharts-tpl.html"

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have add the .fcscript into the asset extensions section.

Here is the code -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import ReactNativeFusionCharts from 'react-native-fusioncharts';

export default class ListenEvents extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const chartConfig = {
      type: 'column2d',
      width: '100%',
      height: '400',
      dataFormat: 'json',
      dataSource: {
        chart: {
          caption: 'Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]',
          subCaption: 'In MMbbl = One Million barrels',
          xAxisName: 'Country',
          yAxisName: 'Reserves (MMbbl)',
          numberSuffix: 'K',
          theme: 'fusion'
        },
        data: [
          { label: 'Venezuela', value: '290' },
          { label: 'Saudi', value: '260' },
          { label: 'Canada', value: '180' },
          { label: 'Iran', value: '140' },
          { label: 'Russia', value: '115' },
          { label: 'UAE', value: '100' },
          { label: 'US', value: '30' },
          { label: 'China', value: '30' }
        ]
      }
    };

    this.state = {
      chartConfig,
      events: {
        // Add your events method here:
        // Event name should be in small letters.
        dataplotclick: (e, a) => {
          Alert.alert(`You clicked on ${e.data.categoryLabel}`);
        }
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Listen to events from chart</Text>
        <View style={styles.chartContainer}>
          <ReactNativeFusionCharts
            chartConfig={this.state.chartConfig}
            events={this.state.events}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10
  },
  header: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 10
  },
  chartContainer: {
    height: 400,
    borderColor: '#000',
    borderWidth: 1
  }
})
```

To know more about it please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/react-native/your-first-chart-using-react-native